Problems building a .jar from a github repo?
I am completely new to github and coding, and I'm trying to build a .jar out of the 1.18.2 branch of https://github.com/Ethonodon/FossilsArcheologyRevival. I have googled like crazy to search for ways to build a jar, and the few methods I've been able to understand have not worked. When I try and build it with commandprompt, it gives me an "unable to get mutable windows environment variable" error. When I try and build it with Eclipse IDE, it won't recognize the files as a "project" despite them being imported and functioning within the application. Supposedly I can also build it directly in github, but I have no idea where I'd do that. I've tried both Java 8 and Java 17 and I run into the same issues with both versions installed. I'm confused- could there maybe be some error on my computer's end, am I doing something wrong, or is there something wrong with the repository itself? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
When I run powershell from the location of the folder containing src and gradlew.bat, I run the command ./gradlew.bat build and run into the error "unable to get mutable windows environment variable". I read this is sometimes caused by some problem in the environment variables, so I googled how to fix that. I made a new variable, JAVA_HOME, and set the value to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17, and added the value %JAVA_HOME%\bin to Path. The same issue still happens.

"I made a new variable" - in PowerShell? Environment of child processes won't automatically inherit native PowerShell variables.

@life888888 Don't need to manually install Gradle 4.10.3, executing the wrapper (like the OP is doing) will automatically download and use the configured version. But you're right that they need to use Java 8, not just because that seems to be the version the mod was targeting but also because Gradle 4.10.3 isn't compatible with Java 11+.

Ok, I've reinstalled Java 8, and the "mutable windows environment variable" issue is gone. HOWEVER, it now says:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728kb object heap

ok, I installed 64 bit java, and now the space issue is gone. When I run "./gradlew.bat build", it runs for about 40 seconds, then fails and says "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'"
